# Compare two sets of correlations

Tags: correlation, p-value, paired-comparisons

I have two sets of pairs:

```
<distance, correlation>
```

where the `correlation` is the Pearson coefficient between two samples, and `distance` is their relative distance according to some measure.

For each value of `distance`, I usually have lots of values of correlation.

I want to test if the correlation in the first set is higher than the correlation in the second one.

What I want to test is if for any fixed  distance, in general the correlations are higher in the first set; I would like to associate a pValue to this.

I have no idea on how to proceed, can you help?

Comment: Ideally, you would want to know the sizes of the samples used to compute each correlation--or, at a minimum, you would want to be sure those sizes were either (a) close to the same or (b) all very large.  So: what do you know about the sample sizes?

Comment: Dear @whuber, each sample is a vector of approximately 200 dimensions. Also, all the samples have the same size.